# comparison of standardised residuals from chi-square goodness of fit test

Tags: chi-squared-test, residuals, normalization, goodness-of-fit

I am analysing the observed distribution of certain amino acid sequence motifs across the superkingdoms against that predicted based on theory using chi-square goodness-of-fit test. In order to find out which motifs contribute the most to chi-square, I plot residuals versus their relative abundance and get a plot as shown. As can be observed, the plots have widely different y-axis. For visual purposes, is it possible to normalize the y-axis so that the range for the residuals of all superkingdoms is similar?

[image]

Comment: If your question is how to align the axes in a plot with multiple panels, that's a programming question better suited to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @dipetkov: The question is not about aligning the the axes in the facet plot but more towards understanding if there is a method to normalize the residuals such that they are within same/similar range.

Comment: Jalan, just divide the residuals by sd(residuals) = Pearson Residuals.

Comment: For a chi-square goodness-of-fit test, there are also "*standardized residuals*" that are commonly used.

Comment: @FlorianHartig: I think these residuals are Pearson Residuals.

Comment: @SalMangiafico: I face a similar problem when plotting standardised residuals. I kind of solved the problem by doing a linear regression on the observed vs predicted, plotting externally studentized residuals and determining outliers based on the criterion of the residuals being +/- 3 absolute values away.

Comment: @Jalan that's what I'm saying, divide by SD = Pearson